# How do people create unofficial api's (which provide json info) for big websites such as imdb?

Tags: json

Such as this api here: http://www.omdbapi.com/

Do they just parse the whole website's HTML and save fields on their own database?

What is a good design, programming-wise?

My simple java developer mentality says this:

1 - Use jsoup (or any other html parsing library) and save the data frequently.

2 - Create restful services that return json, such as "searchByMovieName()", "searchByActor"

3 - Make the services public

Is it simple as that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be, yes.

You can also fetch the pages and scrape the data in real-time (as people call your API). It'll be a little slower but there's less overhead for you and you don't need to worry about stale data.

Comment: Is it legal to do? If yes, Why there are too many unofficial (and sometimes commercial) API's? Where should I know if it's not legal specially if there is no mention in TOS?

Answer (score 0):

IMDB also offers files you can use directly: [Alternative Interfaces](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces)